# restart nginx service without sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

I need to restart the Nginx service without a password attempt.

I find out there is a way with sudoers. so I add blow command in sudoers but it's not working. I have ubuntu 19.4.

```
anonymous  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/systemctl restart nginx
```

so **sudo systemctl restart nginx** must work without any password attempt.

Comment: Are you user `anonymous` on this system?

Comment: yes ofc there is

Comment: Now please close your duplicate question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1224554/421483)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `sudo` events in `/var/log/auth.log`.

Confirm that `systemctl` is in fact at `/usr/sbin/systemctl` (it may be in `/bin/systemctl`).

Ensure that you are running as user `anonymous` on this system for the above `sudoers` to work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password   i chaned to /usr/bin/systemctl.according to that answer. but same reult with : sudo /bin/systemctl restart nginx.service

Comment: What does `which systemctl` return?

Comment: prompt password. this is sudo -l => (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart nginx.service

Comment: To clarify the question, what is the result when you type `which systemctl` on the terminal?

Comment: out put : /bin/systemctl

Comment: You will want to use that exact path in `sudoers`.

Comment: `anonymous  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart nginx`